# SpEL: how does "matches" work?

Tags: regex, operator-keyword, spring-3, spring-el

I have been through the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) for Spring Expression Language and I saw that it has operator **matches** for regular expression. Does anyone know if the algorithm used for it is the same greedy one as for matches in Java language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the basic Java implementation - see `OperatorMatches`...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile((String) right);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher((String) left);
return BooleanTypedValue.forValue(matcher.matches());
```

Comment: It should have cache the pattern rather than compiling it everytime.